# Relative paths not working as expected when using URL Rewrites

Tags: html, asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, iis-6

I'm doing a URL rewrite to a localhost site:

```
<rule name="test" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="demo/(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:7777/{R:1}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
</rule>
```

Let's say the folder structure in localhost:7777 is:

```
/app/something/demo.css
```

and

```
/app/index.html
```

And the call made in the main site is:

http://www.domain.com/afolder/anotherfolder/demo/app/index.html

When I do a simple reference to a css file from index.html which sits in the localhost:7777 website like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/app/something/demo.css">
```

I would expect the path to be: http://www.domain.com/afolder/anotherfolder/demo/app/something/demo.css.

But instead the path becomes:
http://www.domain.com/app/something/demo.css

Even if I try `href="../demo.css"` I would expect to see:
http://www.domain.com/afolder/anotherfolder/demo/app/demo.css

But no... I get: http://www.domain.com/afolder/demo.css

Why :( ?????

Comment: try removing the forward slash at the beginning of the url `app/something`

Comment: nope. Doesn't work. Basically that acts the same as ./

Comment: Firs of all you are doing a rewrite which by definition won't change the path i.e. if I rewrite http://localhost/index.html to http://localhost/redirectedindex.html browser will still only show http://localhost/index.html but load the content from redirectedindex.html. Secondly I am not completely understanding your rewrite rule I don't see nay prefixes like afolder/anotherfolder. Am I missing something?